# Bitwise not in python over unsigned numbers

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, unsigned, bitwise-not

I want to do a bitwise not in Python, but withouth taking care of the sign, as C would do. For example:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> y = ~x
>>> bin(x)
'0b100'
>>> bin(y)
'0b101'
```

In the above code, `y` is `0b101`, but I want it to be `0b011`, literally the bitwise not applied to number `4`. **How can I do this?**

Comment: C wouldn't do what you describe. ~4 in C does not give 3.

Comment: `bin(y)` is not `0b101`, it's `-0b101`, aka `0b..111111011` with an infinite prefix of ones. Putting that aside, can you give more examples of what inputs and outputs you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python ints are both signed and not a defined size of bits, the easiest way is to just XOR with an all 1's mask of the required bit length.

For example to get a NOT for 4 bits:

```
bin(x ^ 0b1111)
```

Test:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> bin(x)
'0b100'
>>> bin(x ^ 0b1111)
'0b1011'
```

Answer (score 2):

you could generate a `mask` of the bit length of `x` and `xor` that with `x`:

```
x = 4  # 0b100
width = x.bit_length()
mask = (1 << width) - 1  # mask = 0b111
y = x ^ mask
print(f"{y:0{width}b}")  # '011'
```